# iOS game localization with lproj directories not working

Tags: ios, libgdx, app-store-connect

My game is localized in 3 different languages. In order to let iTunes Connect know that the game is localized I created these files:

- ios\resources\en.lproj\Localizable.strings
- ios\resources\es.lproj\Localizable.strings
- ios\resources\ca.lproj\Localizable.strings

all three with this content:

```
"AppName"="MechaNika"
```

being *MechaNika* the name of my game.

However, after creating the IPA file and uploading it to iTunes Connect with the Application Loader, it says that my game is only in English, so it seems that I'm missing something.

Note that I'm not using Xcode but libGDX + IntelliJ IDEA + gradle + RoboVM.

That said, do you know how can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it working without any lproj directories, but just adding this to the Info.plist.xml file:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>ca</string>
</array>
```

[Source 1](http://www.telerik.com/forums/localizations-in-app-store-incorrect)

[Source 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-109552)

Comment: jgg, you said you managed to make it work without the lproj directories. But you still need the Localizable.strings files, which contain the translations (eg. en/es/ca). Where do those files go if not in the lproj directories?

Comment: ASFAIK this CFBundleLocalizations values are only used to tell Apple what languages is your app localized to. Actual localization assets must be handled as required by your framework. In my case (libGDX) they are in the "assets" directory of the android project.

Comment: Thanks, jgg. I'm also using libGDX with roboVM. What I want to achieve is to translate the app name that is being displayed when installed on the device (in the app list). Hence your initial question brought my attention: "AppName"="MechaNika" - do you think it's possible to provide multiple app names in the .ipa itself or is this something configurable in Apple's Developer Console?

Comment: Localized names for your app are configured in App Store Connect.